# trying to build a stringBuffer using array

Tags: java, arrays, stringbuffer

Here is my attempt to build a stringBuffer using an array.  How can I fix this?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class StringBufferProj {
public static String appendItems(ArrayList list){
    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i=0; i<list.length(); i++) {
        b.append(list(i));
        b.append(" ");
    }
    return b.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        list.add("StringBuilder ");
        list.add("executes ");
        list.add("multiple ");
        list.add("threads ");
        list.add("at ");
        list.add("a ");
        list.add("time ");
System.out.println(StringBufferProj.appendItems(list));
    }

}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the problem that needs assistance?

Comment: What's the matter with `List.toString()`?

Comment: However, `List` (and `ArrayList`) have a `.size()` method, not `.length`. And `list(i)` is likely supposed to be something akin to `list.get(i)`

Answer (score 1):

First, program to the `List` interface and don't use raw-types. Also, prefer `StringBuilder` to `StringBuffer` and you might use a `for-each` loop.

```
public static String appendItems(List<String> list) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for (String str : list) {
        b.append(str).append(" ");
    }
    return b.toString();
}
```

**or**, in Java 8+, with a stream like

```
public static String appendItems(List<String> list) {
    return list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

And then to invoke it, you might use

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("StringBuilder ", //
            "executes ", "multiple ", "threads ", "at ", "a ", "time "));
    System.out.println(appendItems(list));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(There are better ways to do this in Java. However, based on your original code)
You get an element from the `ArrayList` using [get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-). If you also define the type for the `ArrayList`, then you don't need to cast types and it is much clearer to read:

```
public static String appendItems(ArrayList<String> list) {
    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        b.append(list.get(i));
        b.append(" ");
    }
    return b.toString();
}
```

Comment: And `size()` instead of `length()`.

Answer (score 0):

You code should be something like this

```
public static String appendItems(ArrayList<String> list) {
    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        b.append(list.get(i));
        b.append(" ");
    }
    return b.toString();
}
```

The changes are
1. Method signature - added type for elements of the list `ArrayList<String>`
2. In Java list interface doesn't contain length() method but `size()` method.
3. To get element from the list you should use get method - `list.get(i)`

Since Java 7 you can use enhanced for loop. I would refactor you code to be something like this

```
public static String appendItems(ArrayList<String> list) {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    for (String word : list) {
        buffer.append(word).append(" ");
    }

    return buffer.toString();
}
```

And finally, since Java 8 you can use stream and collectors

```
public static String appendItems(ArrayList<String> list) {
    String result = list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

    return result;
    // or just 
    // return list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```